# Reducing time complexity for the given task

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an item that has a name and a price for it.

Now input for my program contains some list of commands which indicate I can add new item or select an item in the following format:

> Add, item-name, item-price --> Adds item-name with price item-price to my list.
> Select, ,  --> select the item name that has lowest price at index k, and prints to output. If multiple items has same price then select the name in ascending order.

**Example 1:**

**Input :**

```
Add, Apple, 4
Add, Ball, 3
Select, , 
Add, Toy, 5
Add, Pen, 1
Select, ,
```

**Output:**

```
Ball, Ball
```

**Explanation:**

> First we add Apple and Ball. So the items sorted by price [Ball(3), Apple(4)]. Initialize k to 0.
> Then Select has appeared. So get item at index k=0 which is Ball. Now increment k to 1 as a selection has occurred.
> Then we add Toy and Pen. So the items sorted by price [Pen(1), Ball(3), Apple(4), Toy(5)] . Now k is 1.
> Then Select has appeared. So get item at index k=1 which is Ball again. Now increment k to 2 as a selection has occurred.

```
So output is Ball, Ball.
```

**Example 2:**

**Input :**

```
Add, Apple, 4
Add, Ball, 3
Select, , 
Select, , 
Add, Toy, 5
Select, ,
```

**Output:**

```
Ball, Apple, Toy
```

**Explanation:**

> First we add Apple and Ball. So the items sorted by price [Ball(3), Apple(4)]. Initialize k to 0.
> Then Select has appeared. So get item at index k=0 which is Ball. Now increment k to 1 as a selection has occurred.
> Then Select has appeared. So get item at index k=1 which is Apple. Now increment k to 2 as a selection has occurred.
> Then we add Toy. So the items sorted by price [Ball(3), Apple(4), Toy(5)] . Now k is 2.
> Then Select has appeared. So get item at index k=2 which is Toy. Now increment k to 3 as a selection has occurred.

```
So output is Ball, Apple, Toy.
```

This is the code I tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(process(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("Add", "Apple", "4"), Arrays.asList("Add", "Ball", "3"),
                Arrays.asList("Select", "", ""), Arrays.asList("Add", "Toy", "5"), Arrays.asList("Add", "Pen", "1"),
                Arrays.asList("Select", "", ""))));

        System.out.println(process(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("Add", "Apple", "4"), Arrays.asList("Add", "Ball", "3"),
                Arrays.asList("Select", "", ""), Arrays.asList("Select", "", ""), Arrays.asList("Add", "Toy", "5"),
                Arrays.asList("Select", "", ""))));
    }

    public static List<String> process(List<List<String>> input) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        PriorityQueue<Item> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
        int k = 0;
        for (List<String> e : input) {
            if ("Add".equals(e.get(0))) {
                Item a = new Item(e.get(1), e.get(2));
                pq.add(a);
            } else {
                List<Item> sorted = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
                    sorted.add(pq.poll());
                }
                Item itemAtK = sorted.get(sorted.size() - 1);
                list.add(itemAtK.name);
                pq.addAll(sorted);
                k++;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

}

class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
    int price;
    String name;

    public Item(String name, String p) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = Integer.parseInt(p);
    }

    public int compareTo(Item item) {
        int c = price - item.price;
        if (c == 0)
            c = name.compareTo(item.name);
        return c;
    }
```

Here time complexity is I guess `n^2*log(n)`

How to reduce the time complexity for this code.

**Modified code based on stef comments:**

```
public static List<String> process(List<List<String>> input) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        PriorityQueue<Item> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
        for (List<String> e : input) {
            if ("Add".equals(e.get(0))) {
                Item a = new Item(e.get(1), e.get(2));
                pq.add(a);
            } else {
                Item itemAtK = pq.poll();
                list.add(itemAtK.name);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

**Input :**

```
Add, Apple, 4
Add, Ball, 3
Select, , 
Add, Toy, 5
Add, Pen, 1
Select, ,
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Ball, Ball
```

**This program gives wrong output:**

```
Ball, Pen
```

Comment: Rather than increase `k`, could you delete the item at position 0?

Comment: You say the complexity is n² log(n), but you don't say what is n? Is it the number of commands (add, select)? Or is it the number of items in the database?

Comment: n is number of commands. If I delete the item, the I won't get correct output.

Comment: "Initialize k to 0." "`int k = 1;`".

Comment: learner: why would you not get the correct output? If I understand correctly, right now you start with k=0; then every time you get "select", you increment k by 1. You're only ever interested in the item at index k. So, my suggestion is, instead of incrementing k by 1, remove the item at index 0. Then you're only ever interested in the current item at index 0.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I added like that in code just for convenience purpose. In the end, I will pick the element at index 0, then 1 then 2 .... I have updated my code now to avoid that confusion.

Comment: @Stef, I updated the code based on your comments. Now the code is giving the wrong output for example 1 which I mentioned in my post.

Comment: A more efficient implementation would involve a height balanced BST, where you'd also implement the `select(index)` method. Inserting into the BST would be O(log(N)) and querying any index `k` would also be O(log(N), where N is the total number of Add commands, assuming you don't have duplicate commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone commented, perhaps what you need is not a `PriorityQueue`.

Here is an implementation with an unbalanced BST:

```
public static List<String> process(List<List<String>> input) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Item root = null;
    int k = 0;
    for (List<String> e : input) {
        if ("Add".equals(e.get(0))) {
            Item a = new Item(e.get(1), e.get(2));
            root = Item.insert(root, a);
        } else {
            Item first = Item.itemAt(root, k);
            list.add(first.name);
            ++k;
        }
    }
    return list;
}


class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
    int count;
    private Item left;
    private Item right;
    int price;
    String name;

    public Item(String name, String p) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = Integer.parseInt(p);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item item) {
        int c = price - item.price;
        if (c == 0)
            c = name.compareTo(item.name);
        return c;
    }

    public static Item insert(Item root, Item item) {
        if (root == null) {
            item.count = 1;
            return item;
        }
        int c = item.compareTo(root);
        if (c < 0) {
            root.left = insert(root.left, item);
        } else {
            root.right = insert(root.right, item);
        }
        ++root.count;
        return root;
    }

    public static Item itemAt(Item root, int ix) {
        if (root == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (root.left != null) {
            if (ix < root.left.count) {
                return itemAt(root.left, ix);
            }
            ix -= root.left.count;
        }
        if (ix == 0) {
            return root;
        }
        --ix;
        if (root.right != null) {
            if (ix < root.right.count) {
                return itemAt(root.right, ix);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The average complexity is in O(log(n)), but as the tree is unbalanced, there are degenerate cases (when the items are entered sorted).

ERRATA: O(n*log(n))